# How to convert user instance database to normal sql server database

Tags: sql-server, database, user-instance

can anybody help me by providing a link on how to convert a user instance database to normal sql server database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the user instance MDF to a new directory.  From SSMS, right click "Databases" and then Attach.

Comment: @anargha: SSMS = SQL Server Management Studio :)