# Inserting records permanetly into sql server express edition using c#

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

I created a database in sql server express edition, in that i create a table called employee. Now i am able to inserting rows(records) dynamically into table successfully, and i can also read those records successfully. But the problem is the values which are inserted dynamically are stored temporarily. When i close and reopen the application the previous inserted records are not available. can u please suggest me what can i do to save records permanently into the database.

This is my code used to inserting the records into sql server database. Please help me out of this problem...

```
namespace VACS_practice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string m_sVehicleNo, m_sName, m_sFlatNo, m_sImagpath;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Cmd;
        string ConString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\VACSDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            m_sVehicleNo = m_VehicleNo.Text;
            m_sName = m_Name.Text;
            m_sFlatNo = m_Phno.Text;
            //m_sImagpath = m_ImgPath.Text;
            Cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ResidentDB ([R_VehNo],[R_Name],[R_PhNo])   VALUES ('" + m_sVehicleNo + "','" + m_sName + "','" + m_sFlatNo + "')", Con);
            Con.Open();
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully");
            // this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using User Instances?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory, I believe what might be happening is that everytime you run your app, the database might be getting [overwritten by your 'template' .mdf](http://arnulfo.wordpress.com/2007/07/21/visual-studio-and-local-databases/) in your solution. Make sure that your database isn't deployed as "Copy Always" or similar. Alternatively, if your application doesn't need a local / per user database, you can [permanently attach your MDF under the SQL Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202493/how-to-convert-user-instance-database-to-normal-sql-server-database) service.